# How to create iMessage app layout?

Tags: swift3, imessage-extension

When creating a layout for an iMessage Extension app, how do you get the storyboard to mimic the space you'll have the message app? It defaults to an iPhone size, which is way off.

If you layout UI elements on the iPhone sized storyboard and add all of your auto layouts, it will still not look right in the simulator message app.